# How to combine multiple JSON objects where key value is the same

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to combine objects which share the same module key value, i.e. "credit cards". I need to return a single object per unique module with an array of distinct companies. The id and prod keys aren't important.

**Here's the object I need to transform:**

```
const data = [
   {module: "credit_cards", id: "1", company: "ABC", prod: "1"}, 
   {module: "credit_cards", id: "2", company: "XYZ", prod: "2"}, 
   {module: "credit_cards", id: "3", company: "EFG", prod: "2"}, 
   {module: "credit_cards", id: "2", company: "XYZ", prod: "2"}, 
   {module: "mortgages", id: "4", company: "EFG", prod: "3"}
]
```

**I need to return something like this:**

```
const result = [
{module: "credit_cards", company: ["ABC", "XYZ", "EFG"]}, 
{module: "mortgages", company: ["EFG"]}
]
```

So far, I've tried this function:

```
const result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  return Object.keys(e).forEach(function(k) {
    if(!r[k]) r[k] = [].concat(e[k])
    else r[k] = r[k].concat(e[k])
  }), r
}, {})
```

But it just concatenated all the key/values together...

Any help would be awesome, thanks :)

Comment: One key is `company`, while the others' keys are `co_code`, what's the logic behind that?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Good catch, that was a typo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use first [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group the `companies` by the `module` key on a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). On a second step you can use [array.Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the generated object [.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the final desired result:

```js
const data = [
   {module: "credit_cards", id: "1", company: "ABC", prod: "1"}, 
   {module: "credit_cards", id: "2", company: "XYZ", prod: "2"}, 
   {module: "credit_cards", id: "3", company: "EFG", prod: "2"}, 
   {module: "credit_cards", id: "2", company: "XYZ", prod: "2"}, 
   {module: "mortgages", id: "4", company: "EFG", prod: "3"}
];

let res = data.reduce((acc, {module, company}) =>
{
    acc[module] = acc[module] || new Set();
    acc[module].add(company);
    return acc;
}, {})

res = Object.entries(res).map(
    ([module, companies]) => ({module, company: [...companies]})
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` to summarize the array into a `Map`. Use `Set` for unique values.

```js
const data = [{"module":"credit_cards","id":"1","comapany":"ABC","prod":"1"},{"module":"credit_cards","id":"2","comapany":"XYZ","prod":"2"},{"module":"credit_cards","id":"3","comapany":"EFG","prod":"2"},{"module":"credit_cards","id":"2","comapany":"XYZ","prod":"2"},{"module":"mortgages","id":"4","comapany":"EFG","prod":"3"}]

const result = Array.from(data.reduce((c, {module,comapany}) => {
  if (!c.has(module)) c.set(module, new Set);
  c.get(module).add(comapany);
  return c;
}, new Map)).map(([module, comapany]) => ({module,comapany: [...comapany]}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Reduce into an object  indexed by `module`, then take that object's values. Because you only want unique `company` values, use a Set initially, and then transform all items' `company` sets back into an array afterwards:

```js
const data = [
   {module: "credit_cards", id: "1", company: "ABC", prod: "1"}, 
   {module: "credit_cards", id: "2", company: "XYZ", prod: "2"}, 
   {module: "credit_cards", id: "3", company: "EFG", prod: "2"}, 
   {module: "credit_cards", id: "2", company: "XYZ", prod: "2"}, 
   {module: "mortgages", id: "4", company: "EFG", prod: "3"}
]

const result = Object.values(data.reduce(
  (a, { module, company }) => {
    if (!a[module]) a[module] = { module, company: new Set() };
    a[module].company.add(company);
    return a;
  },
  {}
));

result.forEach((item) => {
  item.company = [...item.company];
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Note `XYZ` is duplicated on your `co_code` array. I believe, in relation to his desired output, he don't want duplicated values on the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and with internal check to make sure the list of the companies is unique and without duplicates.

```js
const data = [ {module: "credit_cards", id: "1", company: "ABC", prod: "1"}, {module: "credit_cards", id: "2", company: "XYZ", prod: "2"}, {module: "credit_cards", id: "3", company: "EFG", prod: "2"}, {module: "credit_cards", id: "2", company: "XYZ", prod: "2"}, {module: "mortgages", id: "4", company: "EFG", prod: "3"} ]

let result = data.reduce((r,{module, company}) => {
  r[module] = r[module] || { module, company: [] }
  if(!r[module].company.includes(company))
    r[module].company.push(company)
  return r
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   const data = [
  {module: 'credit_cards', id: '1', company: 'ABC', prod: '1'},
  {module: 'credit_cards', id: '2', company: 'XYZ', prod: '2'},
  {module: 'credit_cards', id: '3', company: 'EFG', prod: '2'},
  {module: 'credit_cards', id: '2', company: 'XYZ', prod: '2'},
  {module: 'mortgages', id: '4', company: 'EFG', prod: '3'}
  ];



 const result = data.reduce((array, item) => {
     const id = array.findIndex(el => el.module === item.module);
     if (id > -1) {
       array[id] = {...array[id], company : [...array[id].company, item.company]};
       return array;
     }
     return [...array, {...item, company : [ item.company]}];
    }, []);
```